# aws-sdk dynamodb add fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

The code below fails with the following error message. I don't see an obvious problem. Am using aws-sdk v3

```
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')",
    "    at AttributeValue.visit (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/models/models_0.js:501:40)",
...
```

```
const { DynamoDBClient, UpdateItemCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
....
const updateRecipientParams = {
        TableName: 'duckies',
        Key: { userId : "sram"},
        UpdateExpression: 'ADD totalReceived :inc',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':inc': 1},
        ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
      };
        const command = new UpdateItemCommand(updateRecipientParams);
        const updatedRecipient = await dynamoDB.send(command);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591418/aws-nodejs-sdk-v3-dynamodb-updateitem-typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-u

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the key has to have a type specified, otherwise it gets interpreted as an array. The change I had to make was

```
Key: { userId : {S:"sram"}},
```

and then it worked fine